# Android action bar options menu item custom selectable background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-actionbar, rippledrawable

I'm trying to use the default android action bar with a custom view:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/customNavigationLayout</item>
</style>
```

The options menu contains a single item which should always show with text:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_cancel" />
```

Now I'm having the issue with the selectable background, which is still the size of an action icon:

[image: How it looks like]

How can I setup the action bar to apply a selectable background which fills the whole box of the item?

[image: How it should look like]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the `android:actionBarItemBackground` attribute in `styles`, like so:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    ...
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the following solutions:

**Solution 1:**

Add `<item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>` to your base application theme with for exmaple:

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
            <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
</style>
```

and

> button_background

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

**Solution 2:**

Use `menuItem.setActionView` to apply a custom layout to your menu item as follows:

> layout_action_cancel (custom menu item layout):

```
<Button
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/b_action_cancel"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background">
</Button>
```

> Then in your onCreateOptionsMenu apply the custom Layout to the menu
>   item:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_action_cancel, null, false);
        menu.getItem(0).setActionView(layout);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

> and in onPrepareOptionsMenu set an OnClick Listener (replacing the
>   onOptionsItemSelected)

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        View layout = menu.getItem(0).getActionView();
        if(layout instanceof Button){
            Button b_action_cancel = layout.findViewById(R.id.b_action_cancel);
            b_action_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //your code
                }
            });
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: I guess this will work. It looks nice on this end. But I really don't want to configure that much just for a menu item. I'd assume it's possible without a big hassle, just with some theme attributes maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can try applying drawable withe selected and normal state at menu item  property :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_cancel" 
    android:icon="@drawable/mybuttonbackground" />
```

Comment: The `icon` will replace the text or show at the start of it. The text or its background is unaffected by it. So sadly this doen't work for me.